# Expected number of digits of the second-largest prime factor of a very large composite number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, expected-value

Suppose, a very large composite number $N$ (let's say $1\ 000$ digits) has no prime factor below some moderate limit (lets say $10^{19}$).

> How can I calculate approximately the expected number of digits of the second-largest prime factor of $N$ ?

I tried to use the asymptotic formula for the number of $y$-rough numbers below $x$, but this lead to nowhere.

Comment: https://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397576900505/1-s2.0-0304397576900505-main.pdf?_tid=89e81c94-2a1b-46c5-9dc9-c341ccbcfb35&acdnat=1544741921_b4f3bb345822d47e9e490849e3b279d1

Comment: journal pages 340 and 341. Reproduced  on page 163 of Hans Riesel, Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization, second edition.

Comment: anyway, at the link, they let you download Knuth and Trabb-Pardo for free.

Comment: @WillJagy The link is broken now sadly.

Comment: @hardmath try download from  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900505